# How to search for any word in a json file with java

Tags: java, json

my goal is to program a function (Ri) that returns the number of rows that contain the term i in json file, for that I started by looking for a word that I initialized, but subsequently I don't know how to generalize. 
This is my start code:

```
public class rit {
private static final String filePath = "D:\\c4\\11\\test.json"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {
        try{
             InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(filePath);
             InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
             BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
             String ligne;
                 String mot="feel";
                 int i=1;
                // nombre de lignes  totales contenant le terme
                int nbre=0; 
             while ((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){

          try {
            // read the json file
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(ligne);

               // get a number from the JSON object
            String text =  (String) jsonObject.get("text");

                        if ( text.contains(mot)){
                        nbre++;
                        System.out.println("Mot trouvé a la ligne " + i );
                        i++;

                        }   

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }}

               System.out.println("number of lines Which contain the term: " +nbre);
    br.close();
 }    
 catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
 }}}
```

And the output is :

```
Mot trouvé a la ligne 1
Mot trouvé a la ligne 2
number of lines Which contain the term: 2
```

If it is possible to generalize, how to do this ?

Comment: try using [`regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `generalize`. Do you mean changing the String `mot` at runtime ?

Comment: I want to search for any word without initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String args[]` in `public static void main(String[] args)` are input parameters. Thus, for running `java rit.class feel`, `args` would be `[feel]`.

You could make your program expect word (and even filePath) in those input argument :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 2){
        // crash the application with an error message
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please enter $filePath and $wordToFind as input parameters");
    }
    String filePath = args[0];
    String mot = args[1];
    System.out.println("filePath : "+filePath);
    System.out.println("mot : "+mot);
}
```

Another way to do so is to wait for user input. It's neat because you can wrap it in a loop and reuse it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // used for scanning user input
    while(true){
        System.out.println("please enter a word : ");
        String mot = scanner.nextLine();  // wait for user to input a word and enter
        System.out.println("mot is : "+mot);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: I have another question, i want to return the number of lines witch contains the term i in the same date, Knowing that I have a json file containing tweets that have different dates. How to proceed?

Comment: I think that needs another StackOverflow question. But in short, you should create a new `class` DatedWord (or anything you like) which contains a keyword and a `Date`, you should then store the date and word in a `Collection` of those objects as you parse the json. You can finally operate a groupingBy reduction based on the date to get what you want.

Comment: The goal is to achieve a function that returns the number of tweets that contain the term i the day of tweet publishing. To begin with I created this program to return the number of tweets that contain a term entered by the user, after that i want to compare the dates and keep only those that have a same date.